# Export selected row using checkbox in dataTables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

Export selected row using checkbox in dataTables.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "multi",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            render: function ( data, type, row ) {
               return row[5]?'':'<input type="checkbox" value="'+row[4]+'">'

         }

        }
    ]
});
```

**First issue** - Export button is not showing on the page.
**Second issue** - How to implement this code correctly to export selected rows.
**I am using normal DOM dataSource for dataTables.**

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this URL](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30544/how-to-export-only-selected-rows)? There has been mentioned about the export function

Comment: This is not an answer, once you have enough rep you should be able to post a comment on a question

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        title: '',
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function(data, row, column, node) {

                    var checkbox = node.previousSibling;
                    if (column === 0 && ($(checkbox).children()[0].checked)) {
                        localStorage.setItem('isSameRow', row);
                        var nodef = $(node).children()[0];
                    }
                    var isSameRow = localStorage.getItem('isSameRow');
                    if (row == isSameRow) {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, ]
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).